# MySQL Select order by custom column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table:

```
id | val | flag
---|-----|------
 1 | 10  |  no
---|-----|------
 2 | 5   | yes
---|-----|------     
 3 | 3   | yes
---|-----|------     
 4 | 25  | no
---|-----|------     
 5 | 8   | no
---|-----|------
```

Basically I want to select `id + custom column` order by `custom column desc` where:

```
custom column = val     (if flag = no)
custom column = val * 2 (if flag = yes)
```

The result of my select should output this:

```
| id | cus | 
|----|-----|
|  4 | 25  |
|----|-----|
|  1 | 10  |
|----|-----|   
|  2 | 10  | 
|----|-----|    
|  5 | 8   | 
|----|-----|    
|  3 | 6   |
|----|-----|
```

Don't ask me what I tried because I am new in mysql. I know how to do this in php, but I guess it's best to handle this from mysql side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when flag = 'no' then val when flag = 'yes' then 2*val end) desc, id;
```

Note:  If `flag` can only be "no" or "yes", then simplify this to:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when flag = 'no' then val else 2*val end) desc, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `case` statement like this

```
select id, val, cus from (
select id, val, case when flag = 'no' then val when flag = 'yes' then val*2 else val end as cus from my_table
) a
order by cus desc;
```

Or, when you don't want an outer select use the case statement also in the order statement as another answer proposes.

The `else` part in the case statement can be used to handle the case if neither yes or no appears. In my example it simply return `val`.

Answer (score 0):

Use case statement.

```
SELECT id,
CASE
  WHEN flag = 'no' THEN val
  WHEN flag = 'yes' THEN val*2
END AS cus
FROM table
ORDER BY cus DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gordon's solution (which demonstrates that you can sort by columns even if they are not part of the result), if you want to include the custom value also in your result, then you could write something like this:

```
select id, if (flag='no',val,val*2) as cus
from mytable
order by cus desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,
       CASE flag
          WHEN 'yes' THEN val*2
          WHEN 'no' THEN val
          ELSE val
        END AS cus
FROM mytable
ORDER BY cus DESC;
```

Comment: This won't work with Mysql. One cannot reuse a column alias at the same level.